# Has anyone created a TypeScript definition file for ractivejs?

Tags: ractivejs

I am working with ractivejs in a large team project where all of our client side javascript is created using TypeScript.  I am wondering if anyone else has run in to the need for a TypeScript definition file for ractivejs?  Thanks for any replies.

Comment: A TypeScript defintion for RactiveJS would be great to have!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have now started create a `ractive.d.ts` :)
https://github.com/codler/Ractive-TypeScript-Definition

Comment: is there somewhere an example how to use ractive with ts ? For example what type is ```Ractive``` what to import from @type/ractive, please?